# PHP API, returning text using JSON

Tags: php, api

I'm currenly writing a basic API, this is just the simple GET and return of some records in a database, so they are all been pushed into an array and returned using json_encode.

But the problem I'm facing is the text; is there a limit? as when i remove the text part it displays each record in `JSON` format but when i add the text field back in the whole return just gives white page, i have all errors turned on and there is nothing displayed on screen errors or in php error logs.

```
$review = array(
   "ReviewID" => $reviewID,
   "Reviewer" => $reviewer,
   "Photo" => $reviewerPhoto,
   "Stars" => $reviewStars,
   "Title" => $reviewTitle,
   "Review" => $reviewText,
   "Date" => $reviewDate,
   "Since" => $timeSince,
   "From" => $reviewFrom
);
array_push($reviewArray, $review);
echo json_encode($apiReturn);
```

So the `Array` field Review should be able to contain the text from the review, this is stored using (TEXT) in the database and some reviews do contain a-lot of characters.

Not sure if there was a limit to what you can display, any help or advice would be great.

Comment: review field - what is a lot of characters? how many?

Comment: @suspectus CHARACTERS = 765 // WORDS = 108

Comment: A generic data dump would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your review text is not super big (which could lead to memory problems), there shouldn't be any problem. `json_encode` should not have any problem processing an array of strings.

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) mentions that "All string data must be UTF-8 encoded", but I think this should in the worst case cause some encoding problem.

Try to be more specific than "the whole return breaks", if you just see a blank page or a generic error page, you should try to enable error display. Relevant thread: [Showing all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

you can try below example to check error in json encode

```
$json = json_encode($data);

if ($json)
    echo $json;
else
    echo json_last_error_msg();
```

PHP docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php